# Python: why is my O(n) slowing down as it progresses?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, slowdown

All I'm doing it iterating over a list of files.  For some reason it shoots right up to about 30% then slows to an infuriating crawl.

I've looked into the files where it should be when it starts slowing, and they do grow in size a bit, but they do not grow linearly and consistently.  Code below:

```
for i in wavs:
    gc.collect()
    print_progress_bar(wavs.index(i)/len(wavs))
    shapes.append(getshape(i.src_path))
```

I was reading that `map()` is a way to speed up loops, but I feel like the loop overhead is not what's growing.  Is `gc.collect()` helping me at all here?

Here are the functions being called:

```
def print_progress_bar(percent):
    done_len = int(percent * progress_bar_length)
    bar = "["
    bar += "=" * done_len
    bar += ">"
    bar += " " * (progress_bar_length - done_len)
    bar += "] "
    bar += str(round(percent*100, 2))
    bar += "%"
    print("\r", end='')
    print(bar+(" " * 5), end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()

def getshape(path):
    if getsize(path) == 0:
            return (0,)

    try:
            this_wav = wave.open(path, 'r')
    except:
            temp_path = "C:\\soundfiles\\tempwav.wav"
            command = ["sox", path , "-r", "8000" ,  "-c" ,  "1", "-e", "unsigned", temp_path]
            convert = subprocess.Popen(command)
            convert.wait()

            this_wav = wave.open(temp_path, 'r')
    finally:
            num_frames = this_wav.getnframes()
            frames = this_wav.readframes(num_frames)
            this_wav.close()
            this_wav_array = list(map(lambda x: x, frames))

            return numpy.fft.fft(this_wav_array).shape or (0,)
```

I tried profiling, but later parts overshadow what is shown here.  This is populating `shapes` list for comparison later.  From what I've checked manually, the wav files requiring exception are pretty evenly distributed.

This is not the 'meat' of the script, but it is getting annoying.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are all the wav's of the same size? Is it possible that the later ones being passed are of bigger sizes, causing the whole thing to slow out?

Comment: Why are you mapping the identify function over  a list?

Comment: Within a range.  20-100KB.  There're not sorted by size though, and it's kind of acting like they are.

Comment: @chepner, because I don't really know how to use numpy.fft, and it was going me valueErrors until I did that map(list()) thing.  Very kludge, I know, will that slow me down?

Comment: It's slower than `list(frames)` (which should work; `list` and `map` both take iterable arguments), but it would fix the slowdown you are describing. It shouldn't be necessary to manually call the garbage collector, either.

Comment: totally unrelated (or maybe not, who knows), but by all mean only catch the *expected* exceptions. Your bare `except` clause is something that should only be followed by a `raise`, really : *YOU DONT KNOW WHAT WENT WRONG SO DON'T ASSUME*

Comment: `gc.collect()` is usually a Bad Idea; the garbage collector runs automatically when needed, and is designed to maximize overall performance.  Running it more often is likely to consume additional overhead.  Worse, it may promote objects out of younger generations too soon, which throws off the whole generational garbage collection system.